# Python: выбрать листы Excel и вывести их в новый файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, excel, pandas

У меня есть excel файл с множеством листов. Нужно создать из него новый excel следующим образом: на первом листе нового файла расположить первый лист старого файла (Stores), а все остальные листы из старого файла объединить в одну таблицу и сложить на второй лист нового файла (Sales).

Все листы, которые нужно объединить в одну таблицу называются примерно одинаково: 'Sales - *Название_города*'. Поэтому я попробовал вытащить их регулярным выражением:

```py
for key in df.keys():
    sales_cities = re.findall('^Sales\s-\s\W*', df)
    if key in sales_cities:
        df_sales.append(df[key])
```

Но вылетает ошибка:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Можно ли как то ее исправить?
Если регулярки не применимы к таким запросам, как по другому можно выбрать и объединить все листы 'Sales - *Название_города*'? (помимо них в excel файле есть множество других, ненужных листов)

Спасибо!

Comment: Вот эта строка у меня вызывает сомнения: sales_cities = re.findall('^Sales\s-\s\W*', df) вы точно в df должны строки искать? И почему это делается внутри цикла, ведь df не меняется при очередной итерации цикла?

Comment: В df лежит собственно файл excel, поэтому искал в нем.
Я, если честно, не так давно учу python, поэтому не знаю, точно ли так нужно делать или есть другой способ вытащить некоторые листы из старого excel и сложить в новый. Буду благодарен, если посоветуете, как это сделать правильно)

Comment: Можете выложить пример excel файла на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Answer (score 1):

Неясно, какую библиотеку вы использовали, но я приведу пример кода для openpyxl

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re

target_sheet_name = re.compile(r'^Sales\s-\s\W*')
assert target_sheet_name.match('Sales - NewYork')
# but
assert not target_sheet_name.match('Sales-Berlin')
assert not target_sheet_name.match('stuff')

workbook = load_workbook('source.xlsx')
target_sheets = []
for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
    if target_sheet_name.match(sheet_name):
        target_sheets.append(workbook[sheet_name])
```